# Unable to load image into UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, uiimage

I have two images on Amazon S3 service. One loads fine and another does not. There isn't an error message.  It just does not load.

```
[doodleImageView setImageWithURL:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/doodlestash/doodles/20/thumb.jpg"];

 //This one does not load.
[doodleImageView setImageWithURL:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/doodlestash/doodles/20/original.jpg"];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `setImageWithURL:` is not a standard `UIImageView` method, please add some info about the category method you're using there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images do both appear to be "valid".  You may want to double check the library you are using and check for typos.  In a quick demo app I did the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImageView* image1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    image1.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/doodlestash/doodles/20/original.jpg"]]];

    UIImageView* image2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
    image2.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/doodlestash/doodles/20/thumb.jpg"]]];

    [self.view addSubview:image1];
    [self.view addSubview:image2];
}
```

I ended up with this:

[image]